# How to transfer Braintree customers to new account

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, braintree

We are taking over an ecommerce site for another customer. It's a woocommerce store. They already have Braintree payments and we need to switch to our existing braintree account.

The problem is that all existing customers are tied to the old braintree account. So all existing customers are getting error 91510 You'll get this error if you create a transaction using a customer ID and the customer ID isn't in your Vault.

If we go into the database and delete everyone's braintree id, then everyone will lose their cc details. Is there anyway to transfer braintree accounts or otherwise get around this customer ID issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge Braintree can export and import the user lists. But you will have to contact them to get it done. As this is a Braintree to Braintree transfer it will be even be easier.

This is an article with a description of the export/import for external gateways, but that is not necessary in your case: [Braintree data migration](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/reference/data-migration)